# Typescript default value of parent interface property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Iparent {
  a: string
}
interface Ichild extends parent {
a: '';
}
const x: child = {}
```

This throws a compiler error when using child
How to provide a default value for `a` in child interface?

Edit:

Class parent actually looks like this:

```
class parent extends React.Component<Iparent> {}

class child extends React.Component<Ichild> {}
```

parent class should have a prop but child class should just have a default value for it i.e. ''

Comment: You can't. Interfaces don't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes:

1. `a: ''` not do default value, it means that a can be only `''` it is like `animal: 'dog' | 'cat'` may be only `'dog'` or `'cat'` value.
2. Interfaces have no default values - they are used like less specified types.
   If you want have default value you should use class child:

```ts
class child implements parent{
    a = '';
}
const x: child = new child();
```